# Erro com construtor

Tags: java, construtor, getters-setters

```
MyCircle c = new MyCircle(2,5,8);/// Instanciei um objeto no main.
```

---

```
public class MyCircle {

    private MyPoint center; 
    private int radius=1;

    public MyCircle(int x,int y,int radius) {

       this.center.getX(x); ///na classe MyPoint ha a variável x e y com os respectivos gets e sets
       this.center.setY(y);
       this.radius = radius;

    }
```

> ```
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: questao.MyPoint.getX
>     at questao.MyCircle.<init>(MyCircle.java:17)
>     at questao.Questao.main(Questao.java:27)
> C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
> ```

Comment: `getX` e `setY` são estáticos? Caso não sejam, você tem que instanciar `MyPoint`

Comment: Pq nao poderia criar center e atribuir os valores de center no construtor? (aprendendo java ainda ,n cheguei a olhar static )

Comment: Se possível clica em [edit] e posta o erro, fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: coloquei o erro que é mostrado.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é um problema de compilação. Não há um método `getX` que receba um `int` como parâmetro na classe `MyPoint`.

Entretanto, isso faz sentido, pois *getters* não têm parâmetros. A ideia desse código parece ser definir qual é o centro e não descobrir qual ele é. Em outras palavras, você deveria chamar o *setter* (`setX`), e não o *getter* (`getX)`. Observe que com o Y, você faz certo e chama o *getter* (`getY`). Ou seja, o que você queria era isso:

```
public class MyCircle {
    private MyPoint center; 
    private int radius;

    public MyCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
       this.center.setX(x);
       this.center.setY(y);
       this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

Mas mesmo se você arrumar esse problema, ainda vai dar um `NullPointerException` porque você não pode chamar o *setter* do objeto `center` quando ainda não existe um objeto `center`. A solução é essa:

```
public class MyCircle {
    private MyPoint center; 
    private int radius;

    public MyCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
       this.center = new MyPoint();
       this.center.setX(x);
       this.center.setY(y);
       this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPoint {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public MyPoint() {
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

No entanto, ainda há mais uma questão a considerar. Observe que o `MyCircle` é construído por meio de parâmetros do construtor enquanto que o `MyPoint` é construído por meio de *setters*. A abordagem baseada em parâmetros do construtor costuma produzir código mais fácil de se mexer, mais fácil de se entender, mais simples, menor e menos propenso a produzir surpresas desagradáveis. Assim sendo, vamos mudar a abordagem de `MyPoint` para usar a abordagem baseada em parâmetros do construtor:

```
public class MyCircle {
    private MyPoint center; 
    private int radius;

    public MyCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
       this.center = new MyPoint(x, y);
       this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPoint {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```